# Samsung Knox SDK problems

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile

I could not find what is the KLM_KEY, also I'm having problems with the ELM_Key I have  placed my key in the SAConstants ELM_Key, but still it tells me that i need to add the ELM_KEY.I have browsed all the documentation, it explains what is the KLM_KEY but there is no refference to it, that is the most confuzing part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's sample code to activate your ELM key:

```
EnterpriseLicenseManager elm = EnterpriseLicenseManager.getInstance(this);
elm.activateLicense("123456");
```

Of course you'd want to replace the string I used with the constant you're using for your ELM key.